# Gnome 3.4.2: How to display notifications a bit longer

Tags: debian, gnome, notifications, gnome-shell

I receive mails via Thunderbird (with extensions FireTray and GNOME Integration) and want to display the "New mail notification" a bit longer.

How can I increase the length of time notifications are displayed in Gnome 3.4.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT` is set to 4 seconds in `gnome-shell` `ui` files, namely

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/messageTray.js
```

so changing the timeout is only a matter of editing that file, specifically this line:

```
const NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT = 4;
```

and replacing the default value (`4`) with whatever suits you.
Restart shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> , <kbd>r</kbd> for the changes to take effect.